# Were any creatures native to Praxis?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, praxis

Praxis, the moon of Qo'noS, was colonised by Klingons from the home planet, whose economy, although not literally their home world, was destroyed by its explosion.

But **were there any beings *native* to Praxis**, who evolved there and preceded the Klingons' arrival? If so, were any such species completely annihilated by the explosion, or did they survive on Qo'noS or elsewhere?

Comment: I highly approve of this question, despite its implications for my person.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, at least not as documented in [primary](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Praxis) nor [secondary](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Praxis) canon.

Additionally:

> In a scripted line not included in the actual film, Praxis was to have been established as having no indigenous lifeforms.

Answer (score 5):

## It seems there aren't any indigenous lifeforms...

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Praxis):

> Praxis was the inhabited sole natural moon of Qo'noS. It was used as
>   the Klingon Empire's key energy-production facility in the 23rd
>   century.

However, by 'inhabited', this seems to be referring solely to those Klingons who inhabited Praxis

[Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Praxis) also states that:

> In 2293 over-mining and insufficient safety precautions led to the
>   destruction of Praxis in a massive explosion. The shockwave from the
>   explosion damaged Qo'noS's ozone layer, hit the USS Excelsior, and the
>   remains of the moon formed an asteroid belt around Qo'noS which
>   threatened all life on the Klingon homeworld. Klingon scientists
>   estimated Qo'noS would not be able to support life just thirty-four
>   years after the disaster and the Federation predicted the fall of the
>   Klingon Empire within fifty years as a result. (TOS movie &
>   novelization: The Undiscovered Country; TOS novel: Sarek; TOS comic:
>   "The Order of Things")

Note how ecological damage is referred to on Qo'noS *only*; surely if there were indigenous life forms on Praxis, that would have been mentioned somewhere as well.

Additionally, Memory Beta explains that in an alternate reality:

> Having reached a stalemate in the five year war, the Federation felt
>   that deployment of the device on Praxis would act as a demonstration
>   of force and lead to a possible Klingon surrender. Although the moon
>   had a population of about 500,000, the Federation thought that **since
>   most either lived underground or in colonies protected by shields and
>   domes, the inhabitants would be spared any ill-effects from the
>   Genesis wave as it re-formed the moon's surface.**

This suggests to me that Praxis wasn't really suitable for any native life forms to survive naturally.

## but...

Memory Beta also mentions that at some point **an Iconian gateway had been placed on Praxis**, so possibly, whilst not native, ***some* life forms may have arrived at Praxis *prior to* the Klingon arrival.**

Comment: Good, well-referenced answer (+1) ... but I think the quote from @Politank-Z clinches it much more succinctly.

Comment: @randal'thor most definitely; I'm pleased with my answer but Politank-Z's is far more definitive and authoritative!  Please do accept it 